# Laravel eloquent relation error - Call to undefined relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables `schools` and `subscriptions`. I already get the `school_id` from my `subscriptions` table. My problem is when I want to get the `description` column from `schools` table. I get an error `Call to undefined relationship [description] on model [App\Subscription].` Can someone tell me what is the problem of my codes? I already defined the relationship in my models and in the migration. I don't want to use querybuilder because its too confusing. Thanks.

Schools Model

```
class School extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['description'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }


    public function subscriber()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subscription','description');
    }
}
```

Subscription Model

```
class Subscription extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'school_id', 'start_date', 'end_date',
    ];

    public function subscriptions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\School','description');
    }

    public function plans(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Plan');
    }
}
```

My controller

```
 $subs = Subscription::findOrFail($id)->with('description')
                                  ->get();    
            $plans = Plan::get();
            dd($subs);
```

PS. When i only put`$subs = Subscription::findOrFail($id);` I get this data in `dd`

```
 #attributes: array:8 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "school_id" => 2
    "start_date" => "2019-09-27"
    "end_date" => "2019-10-27"
    "created_at" => "2019-10-17 03:36:13"
    "updated_at" => "2019-10-17 03:36:13"
    "plan_id" => 2
    "status" => 1
  ]
```

Schools Table

```
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(191)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| description  | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| logo         | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| main_server  | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| local_server | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status       | int(11)          | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| updated_by   | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Subscriptions

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| school_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_date | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_date   | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| plan_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| status     | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

EDIT: I just want to get the `description` from `school_id` that i get from `$subs`

Comment: Check the `belongsTo` parameters.. do the two tables join on `description` column?

Comment: @Vince description function is not found in Subscription Model

Comment: In your **Subscription Model** we cannot see a function called `description`.

Comment: My table `subscriptions` does not have a column `description` sir. Thats why i didint put description into it. Am i wrong? @GayanS.Muthukumarana

Comment: No sir. They only join on `subscriptions.school_id` and `school.id` @TahaPaksu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Subscription Model change the relation function subscriptions

```
public function subscriptions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\School', 'id', 'school_id');
    }
```

call the eloquent query to

```
$subs = Subscription::with('subscriptions')->findOrFail($id);
dd($subs->subscriptions[0]->description);
```

Comment: i just want to get the description of the school sir by the `school_id` i get from `dd`

Comment: @Vince for description call $subs->subscriptions->description

Comment: I got this `Property [subscriptions] does not exist on this collection instance.` error sir

Comment: @Vince subscriptions function is there in Subscription model,right? also check the edited query

Comment: yes sir. I Changed my code to yours but when i ` dd($subs->description);` It returns `null`

Comment: @Vince call like this $subs->subscriptions->description

Comment: `Property [description] does not exist on this collection instance.` error sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200995/discussion-between-rp9-and-vince).

Answer (score 1):

You call wrong relation. You have defined `subscriptions` and not `description` relation in your `Subscription Model`.

Maybe it's typo?

you can change your relationship to :

```
public function description(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\School','id', 'school_id');
}
```

and then just call it like:

```
$subs = Subscription::with('description')->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: What do you mean sir? I changed my code to yours and i get `Call to undefined relationship [subscriptions] on model [App\Subscription].` error

Comment: I added my table structure pls help

Comment: You have to change your relationship

Comment: @Vince, When you make relationship you have to point out the how two tables are connected. In this case shool_id from Subscription == id from Schoold so: 

`public function subscriptions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\School', 'id', 'school_id');
    }`

Comment: you should change your relationships in all Models to my opinion

Comment: can you edit your answer sir? im confused a bit here in comment

Comment: Ive made some changes i added some code and it works.

Comment: nice, good luck forward, please upvote my answer if it helps, thanks